# How to detect swipe gesture across multiple views in android?

Tags: java, android, touch-event, event-listener, android-gridlayout

I have a **Grid Layout** with multiple **TextViews** as children. I have added an event listener to each TextView. I want to detect when a user swipes across multiple TextViews in the layout

i.e. ***I want to identify all the TextViews that have been touched while swiping.***

I recieve touch event for only the first TextView that has been touched , I do not receive any touch events for other TextViews when user swipes his finger across multiple TextViews in GridLayout.

I have tried using

```
 TextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
```

,

```
TextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        }
    });
```

and

```
 TextView.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I have also tried overriding

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
}
```

What should i do now ?

Answer (score 0):

try to grid view ItemClickListener.

grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get the GridView selected/clicked item text
                String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                // Display the selected/clicked item text and position on TextView
                tv.setText("GridView item clicked : " +selectedItem
                        + "\nAt index position : " + position);
            }
        });